# I need to query against a column name using SQL in ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic

So I need to make multiple queries based on the string name within a column. I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. In my DivisionNew table there is a column name JMSDay with the values of "Sunday" and "Monday"

```
<% 
Set rssun = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "SELECT * FROM DivisionNew WHERE JMS_UpdateDateTime >= DATEADD(day,-7,
GETDATE()) AND JMSDay = 'Sunday'"
rssun.Open sql, db

Capacity = rssun ("SunCapacity")

%>

<% 
Set rsmon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "SELECT JMSDay FROM DivisionNew WHERE JMS_UpdateDateTime >= DATEADD(day,-7,
GETDATE()) AND JMSDay = 'Monday'"
rsmon.Open sql, db

Capacity = rsmon ("MonCapacity")
%>
```

The query results will then be placed within a table.

```
<table>
   <tr>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
        </tr>

           <tr>

    <td class="Sunday">

<input type="text"  name="Sun-Capacity" id="Sun-Capacity"  
value="<%=SunCapacity %>" />
    </td>

<td class="Monday">
<input type="text"  name="Mon-Capacity" id="Mon-Capacity" 
value="<% =MonCapacity %>"  />
</td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

I'm not sure if my queries are correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is here. What happens when you run the queries? Do you get the results you'd expect?

Comment: Your question is tagged MySQL but your SQL queries are written using SQL Server functions.

Comment: My apoligies, I just removed the MySQL tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your queries are not correct. However, I don't know what the correct queries will be. Here are the issues:

- The Sunday query will return a bunch of rows and a bunch of columns. It looks like you're only looking for one value to stick in your HTML. It's not clear which value you want. You probably want to do something like `SUM(value)` in your select clause: `SELECT SUM(capacity) FROM DivisionNew WHERE JMS_UpdateDateTime >= DATEADD(day,-7,
  GETDATE()) AND JMSDay = 'Sunday'`
- The Monday query is off. You're returning JMSDay where JMSDay = 'Monday'. So you'll get a bunch of rows full of 'Monday'. You probably want to return a different column.
- Not related to your question: You're using the same ID and name twice in your HTML. You won't be able to tell which input was which.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the multiple ID issue within my code. A mistake I over looked. Well the intention of my question was to make sure that it was correct. I think I need to rephrase my question and find out how to do a loop, so that I can get multiple results.